# isalpha() function not working for spaces in string

Tags: c++, tolower, isalpha

I wrote a code so that it removes everything(like spaces and other things) other than the alphabats using isalpha() function and converts it to lower case using tolower() function. It is working fine if i don't put a space in the string but if there is any space in the string then it go beyond the space. I dont understand why this is happening. This is the code i wrote.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<cctype>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i;
    string A,b="";
    cin>>A;
    for(i=0;i<A.size();i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(A[i]))
        b+= tolower(A[i]);
        
        else
        continue;
        
    }
    cout<<b;
}
```

Please help me.
Thankyou

Comment: What is the input for which it is failing? What is the output you are getting on that test case ? What is the expected output?

Comment: So many duplicate questions to choose from...

Comment: Add this line `cout << A << '\n';` Then you might understand what is happening

Comment: Like i give input= "adhGHt//'[]\Klj  hyjc//ghDf" then it will return output as adhghtklj instead of returning adhghtkljhyjcghdf

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that `else continue;` can be removed. It doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 5):

The `cin >> A;` considers the space to terminate the input.

To get the whole line, use `getline(cin, A);`

Answer (score 4):

`cin` reads the string till the first space it encounters, if your input string is "Hello World", then cin will only read "Hello".

You can use [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) function to read a complete line.